# High Order Function IF ELSE check

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I've an imported module with two functions

```
def kind1(paramA, paramB)
    ...

def kind2(paramA, paramB)
```

I pass at random one of these two functions to an object by its constructor.

```
object = Constructor(param1, param2, function)
```

Now with

```
>>> print object.function
```

I get

```
function kind1 at 0xb124...
```

or

```
function kind2 at 0xb1464...
```

how can I check if object.function is of kind1 or of kind2?

I've tried with

```
if object.function == kind1:
    print 'kind1'
elif object.function == kind2:
    print 'kind2'
```

and with

```
if object.function == kind1():
    print 'kind1'
elif object.function == kind2():
    print 'kind2'
```

and I've tried also

```
if isinstance(object.function, kind1):
    print 'kind1'
elif isinstance(object.function, kind2):
    print 'kind2'
```

but they obviously didn't work. 
What's the right way to perform this check?

Comment: can you give a real example for more clearence?

Comment: They're not defined because they're not yet in your namespace. Give some actual code, or at least use actual python terminology. Is `kind` a class in another module?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to refer the function (method) as `ObjectInstance.kind1`, and `ClassOfObject.kind1`

Since 
`type(ClassOfObject.kind1) == <class 'function'>` and 
`type(ObjectInstance.kind1) == <class 'method'>` and have different addresses is hard to compare directly, a workaround is use some attributes to compare it (like `.__name__` or making your own ones)

Comment: thank you...I forgot the existence of .__name__
the solution is "if object.function.__name__ == kind1" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code samples do not match your described behaviour, assigning a function object to an attribute does not change the identity of that object:

```
def foo():
    pass

class Klass(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

a = Klass(foo)
print(a.f is foo)  # True
print(a.f == foo)  # True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`id`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function, which checks for object identity:

```
def foo():
    pass
def bar():
    pass
def whatisit(fn):
    case = {
       id(foo) : "foo",
       id(bar) : "bar",
    }
    print "got function %s" % case[id(fn)]
# see what we get     
whatisit(foo)
whatisit(bar)
=>
got function foo
got function bar
```

Note that using `fn.__name__` may be acceptable or not, depending on your particular system (in some systems, this would be considered a security risk):

```
def foo():
    pass
def sybil():
    pass
# let's be evil
sybil.__name__ = 'foo'
# social engineering ;-)
print foo.__name__ == sybil.__name__
#=> True
# always check identity
print id(foo) == id(sybil)
#=> False
```

If you must rely on the name instead of id (e.g. if you pass the function to a sub- or remote process), at least use the safe path in the [read-only code object](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#index-59):

```
# the unforgeable name, similar to a fingerprint
print foo.__code__.co_name == sybil.__code__.co_name
#=> False
```

In case you wonder about the fancy name of the malicious function, check out Wikipedia's [Alice and Bob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob#Cast_of_characters).